# Can''t get JavaScript to work in WebView

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

I have a fairly simple JavaFX application. It has one window, split in two.  On the left is a tableview that lists rows from a database.  When you select one of the rows, it displays the XML (also from the database) in a webview on the right.  So far so good.  I can't for the life of me get any sort of JavaScipt working.  My ultimate goal is to get a search and highlight working (as in this [great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418626/javafx-search-and-highlight-text-add-search-bar-for-loaded-web-page).  Based on my problems there, I thought I'd try and simplify matters by just plugging in a simple JavaScript function to the HTML.

I'm using FXML, if that's relevant.  I have a button that for it's OnAction property, calls this method:

```
    @FXML
    private void searchBrowser() {
        if (webEngine.getDocument() != null) {
            highlight(searchField.getText());           
        } 
    }

    @FXML
    private void highlight(String text) {
        webEngine.executeScript("test()");
```

It doesn't throw any errors, and both methods are called in order. Just nothing else happens.  The test() function is in the HTML, just a simple alert.  If I just save the HTML and load it in Chrome or IE, the function works fine.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I made changes to my post. Take a look. And it would be also g8 to see how you add you js and XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I can't find easy way to fix old version for `webView.getEngine().loadContent();`.

But i decided to push the same feature on my project. My requirements where *syntactic highlight* and *selected text highlight*, so here is what i came up with: (Code is not really optimised, just works and demonstrates how it can be done)

It is huge code for 1 post ,so i will just explain essential parts and post demo git link. [Java git path.](https://github.com/varren/JavaFXWebViewPrettyXML/tree/master/src/main/java/sample), [Resources git path](https://github.com/varren/JavaFXWebViewPrettyXML/tree/master/src/main/resources)

- Google-code-prettify lib for syntactic highlight
- JQuery + 2 js   functions for selected text highlight.
- Initially I load `template HTML` file as a string and fix css and js
  links, because i store them locally and have no idea how to setup relative path in html
- Then I wrap `html encoded XML` in template HTML

[image]

> **Old Post works only for `webView.getEngine().load()`:**
>
> I don't know what's inside `test()` js function, but this code looks
>   fine to me. The problem can be when you append your js to the page,
>   because `webView.getEngine().load()` and
>   `webView.getEngine().loadContent();` are both assync tasks, so you
>   have to add listener like this:
>
> ```
> webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
>             new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
>                 public void changed(ObservableValue ov, 
>                                     Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
>                     if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
>                         //some append js code here
>                     }
>                 }
>             });
> ```
>
> **And here is working demo code: https://gist.github.com/varren/1fb41536f2b95f69be4e**

Comment: After adding the listener to my code, I get this error when I try the execute Script method: `netscape.javascript.JSException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $`.

Comment: Well, okay, this is getting wierd. If I plug in a "real" url (webView.getEngine().load(http://someurlgoeshere), everything works.  When I load the xml message using loadContent, that's when I get the error,

Comment: Thank you so much!  Once I used your method for injecting the XML into the HTML, it worked perfectly.